# i want to print the non repeated number using hashmap;

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
// Driver Code Starts
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> printNonRepeated(int arr[], int n);

int main() {
  int t;
  cin >> t;
  while (t--) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cin >> arr[i];

    vector<int> v;
    v = printNonRepeated(arr, n);

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      cout << v[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

// } Driver Code Ends

// Function to print the non repeated elements in the array
// arr[]: input array
// n: size of array
vector<int> printNonRepeated(int arr[], int n) {
  vector<int> a;
  unordered_map<int, int> h;
  int count = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    h[arr[i]]++;
  }
  int j = 0;
  for (auto x : h) {
    if (x.second == 1) {
      a[j] = x.first;
      j++;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

I want to print the nonrepeating numbers using the function `vector<int> printNonRepeated(int arr[],int n)`. I am trying using hashmap. I am getting segmentation error while compiling. Where am I doing a mistake.
I do not have the permission to change the main function. I can only change the 'printNonRepeated' function.

Comment: *I am getting segmentation error while compiling* -- No, you are getting this error when running the program, not compiling the program.  Second, this: `int arr[n];` is not valid C++.  You are already using `std::vector`, so you should be using it there also: `std::vector<int> arr(n);`

Comment: `a[j] = x.first;` -> `a.push_back(x.first);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a[j] = x.first;
j++;
```

You can't access the `j`th index of `a` without having allocated space first. The size of the array needs to be predefined, or you can use `push_back` so that the vector adds a new element to the end.

```
a.push_back(x.first);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters variable length arrays as this

```
int n;
    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];
```

is not a standard C++ feature.

You may not use the subscript operator with an empty vector.

```
  vector<int> a;
  //...
  for (auto x : h) {
    if (x.second == 1) {
      a[j] = x.first;
      j++;
    }
```

Creating vectors is redundant. You could initially store entered values in a container of the type `std::map` declared in main.